# Questions I already flagged should not show up on the review queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

I flagged a question and afterwards I checked the low-quality review queue.

The same question I just flagged showed up there. So I decided I am going to reject it again, which was not possible, showing me the dialog that I already flagged this post. The only possible course of action for me was to skip the question.

However, in my opinion it would be much more logical if question I already flagged did not show up in the low quality review queue. There is really no point in showing this post to the same user again.